# Wordpress error: Blog page redirection issue

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I am facing a weird issue in WordPress, I have to 2 URL's

1. xyz.com/features/feature-details - this is a page link
2. xyz.com/blog/feature-details-using-xyz - this is a blog link

Now the issue here is when someone opens the blog link then page which renders has both features page and blog page rendered one below the other. But when someone visits the feature page it loads properly.

The solutions which I already tried are as follows:

1. I tried clearing the slug
2. I tried re-naming the URL of the Page and Blog both
3. I have tried clearing the cache

The problem is happening with all the url's which has some part of the url in common i.e. 'feature-details' in the above example.

Is there anything that I am missing or doing wrong?